# Text.text property doesn't show up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am making a pong game in Unity, but am running into a problem with editing text. I have a canvas with UI text inside of it. The problem with my code is that in my `public Text mytext`: MonoDevelop or Visual Studio can't find a definition for `mytext.text`. My code does not compile.

I have already included `using UnityEngine.UI`, but still doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class balls : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Text mytext;
    public bool left;
    public bool upwards;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (left == true) {
            gameObject.transform.Translate (Vector3.left * 6 * Time.deltaTime);
        } else 
        { 
            gameObject.transform.Translate (Vector3.right * 6 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (gameObject.transform.position.y > 4.2 || gameObject.transform.position.y < -4.2) 
        {
            if (upwards == true) {
                upwards = false;
            } else 
            {
                upwards = true;
            }
        }
        if (upwards == true) 
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate (Vector3.up * 6 * Time.deltaTime);
        } else
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * 6 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (gameObject.transform.position.x > 7.82 || gameObject.transform.position.x < -7.82) 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("Pong");
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Paddle")
        {
            mytext.text = "4";
            if (left == true) {
                left = false;
            } else 
            {
                left = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that VS can't find `myText.text`? Do you mean that your IDE underlines this in red? Does the code compile, but not run properly? What?

Comment: @Draco18s it just says "Text contains no definition for text"

Comment: delete text field  and build text field  again by drag and drop Or check text box properties.somehow attached textbox event must have deleted.

Comment: Right click on the Text type and go to definition. See if it actually leads to the Unity Text or another.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure -

Drag your text object into the `mytext` text slot of your script in the editor.

Run the scene, the `OnTriggerEnter` can be triggered and the obtained gameObject's tag is `Paddle`.

**Edit:**

Avoid custom class with the same name.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1340078/type-text-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-text.html

Comment: The `OnTriggerEnter` is not my problem. It is that MonoDevelop says that Text doesn't contain a definition for text. Also, it won't even let me drag the text into the slot.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this script. Have you tried on this? https://answers.unity.com/questions/1340078/type-text-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-text.html

Comment: yes that worked, really weird how that works. thanks though.

Comment: @TannerH. Its not weird at all.

Comment: Which line of code? Make sure `mytext` is initialized

Comment: Well for some reason now it works just fine without `AddComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it

```
UnityEngine.Text myText;
```

Sometimes Unity does this issue I don't know.